# Empty Media Library while Editing Posts/Pages but appear when inserting New Posts/Pages

Tags: wordpress, image, media, media-library

So I had a problem after moving my wordpress host to another host and setting multilingual plugin, I can't seem to insert new image from media library while editing existing page. It shows blank media library but the truth is there are hundres of images in my Media > Library. Strangely, the insert new image from media library in new post/pages works fine, it's just not working in editing posts/pages. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind. Solved already. It was because of Polylang Plugin activated. Go to Settings > Languages > uncheck the "Activate Language and Translation for Media" Voila! The media library will not appear empty amymore!

Comment: You sir, are a life saver! Thanks a bunch!